# Multiple post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm using the "Types" plugin for Wordpress to create two custom post types and it works fine. I built custom templates on the base of archive-slug.php where the "slug" is the post type slug. It applies everything fine, but in my navigation - I open a single custom post type, but it marks the page with the default post type as active.

Seems to be a conflict and WP can't figure out which menu item to mark as active so it uses the menu item that is a category page for the default post type instead of the custom one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set `has_archive` to true and flushed your permalinks

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yes. Basically, my file structure is: home.php for regular posts, archive-news.php for blog posts (custom post type). I have two menu items - one for the regular posts category page (BLOG) and another one for NEWS. When I open NEWS and an individual NEWS post - the nav bar marks the BLOG as the active menu item. Likewise, when I open NEWS (category page), both the NEWS and BLOG are marked as active.

If it makes a difference, I'm using the ROOTS starter theme.

Comment: archive-news.php is for the news posts (not blog posts) - error in the above response, sorry

Comment: Sorry, but this is related to the theme and/or plugin you are using. Both of these are off topic unfortunately. Please contact the author of the theme and/or plugin

Comment: I am the creator of the theme - that's why I'm struggling with this. I'm fairly sure it's the file structure that's causing the issue which is WP related so was hoping for some help...

Comment: Then please show us the code for your menu (and a dummy CPT). Give us something that helps reproducing the issue. Else it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Multiple Custome Post of your Website ? you told that you have already created one custom post of your website. Don't worry about it. Now I will help you for your problem

First, make an another custom posts on your and paste function.php or custom-posts.php file. Now I will create custom post **Movie** Types . you can just change it **Movie** replaces it your custom post type name.

```
    function custom_post_type() {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Movies', 'Post Type General Name' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Movie', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Movies'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Movie' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Movies'),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Movie'),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Movie'),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Movie' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Movie' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Movie'),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash'),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'movies' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Movie news and reviews' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',

        // This is where we add taxonomies to our CPT
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'movies', $args );

}



add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

**Displaying Multiple Post Types**

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?> 
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```